# Casting shadows on textured meshes

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using gazebo 1.3.1, objects do not cast shadows on textured objects.

How to reproduce: start an empty world, add a coke can and a cube. The can casts shadows on the cube (and the ground), but the cube does not shadow the can (it shadows only the ground).

Importance: I would like to use a texturized terrain with shadows on the ground.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/883/casting-shadows-on-textured-meshes/) by [rasmus25](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156/rasmus25/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

With the current version of Gazebo and the version of  Ogre in Ubuntu, shadows will be cast on textured objects as long as the texture is not tiled.

This will be fixed in the next version of Ogre.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0